# Angular ng-repeat list value spliting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm storing below data in localstorage and i wanted to retrieve these values in html page for search history(assume search history is an list).

```
hotelSearchCriteria = {
        destination : location,
        datesInfo:{
            checkInDate : '2017/05/22',
            checkOutDate: '2017/05/30'
        }
}
localStorage.setItem("hotelSearchCriteria", JSON.stringify(hotelSearchCriteria));

var storedInfoArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hotelSearchCriteria'));
if(storedInfoArray != null){
    $scope.storedInfoArrayAngular = storedInfoArray;
}
```

I want to retrieve these value using ng-repeat and i need to split checkInDate and checkOutDate as follows "05/22 (Mon) - 05/30 (Tue)"
        I can able store data in localStorage successfully as a list but i'm facing issue in retrieving these list of values. How can i split dates in ng-repeat ?

```
<li ng-repeat="storedInfo in storedInfoArrayAngular">
    <p>{{storedInfo.destination}}</p> 
    <span>{{storedInfo.checkInDate}}</span> - <span>{{storedInfo.checkOutDate}}</span>
</li>
```

**Expected result**

Search History

Singapore

05/22 (Mon) - 05/30 (Tue)

Tokyo

05/22 (Mon) - 05/30 (Tue)

Anybody can help me out ? Thanks in advance

Comment: need to delete search history one by one when user click delete and that data should be removed from localStroage as well. Could you please suggest me for this ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `checkInDate` and `checkOutDate` are properties of the `storedInfo.datesInfo`, so you should use the full object path when referring to it:

```
<li ng-repeat="storedInfo in storedInfoArrayAngular">
    <p>{{storedInfo.destination}}</p> 
    <span>{{storedInfo.datesInfo.checkInDate}}</span> - <span>{{storedInfo.datesInfo.checkOutDate}}</span>
</li>
```

And to format your dates as *05/22 (Mon)* you can use the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) as follows:

```
{{ storedInfo.datesInfo.checkInDate | date: "MM/dd (EEE)" }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @arthur hess. Your solution got fixed my issue.

Comment: I need to delete search history one by one when user click delete and that data should be removed from localStroage as well. Could you please suggest me for this ?